# Wordpress не работает пагинация

Tags: php, wordpress

Не работает пагинация постов

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php

        $posts = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => 10,
            'orderby'     => 'date',
            'order'       => 'DESC',
            'post_type'   => 'post',
            'suppress_filters' => true,
        ) );

            
        foreach($posts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post); 
    ?>
            
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="article-item">
        <div class="article-item__img">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="article-item__content">
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>
    </a>

    <?php } wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
    <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/

Answer (score -1):

Пагинация довольно часто не работает с get_posts(). Попробуйте переделать свой цикл на WP_Query:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'orderby'     => 'date',
        'order'       => 'DESC',
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'suppress_filters' => true );

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
$wp_query->the_post();
//  ваш вывод
?>      
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" 
 classs="article-item">
    <div class="article-item__img">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="article-item__content">
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>
</a>

<?php }

// пагинация
the_post_pagination();

// вернем global $wp_query
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Откройте хоть раз код get_posts и не пишите чушь.